# Updating multiple attributes of a python object - unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

```
import requests


class RadioInfo:
    def __init__(self, url, station_num=0):
        self.url = url
        self.station_num = station_num

    def update(self):
        radio_info = self.get_json()
        self.update_info(radio_info)

    def get_json(self):
        r = requests.get(self.url)
        return r.json()[self.station_num]

    def update_info(self, radio_info):
        self.radio_station_name = radio_info["station"]["name"]
        self.radio_station_description = radio_info["station"]["description"]
        self.current_listeners = radio_info["listeners"]["current"]
        self.unique_listeners = radio_info["listeners"]["unique"]
        self.total_listeners = radio_info["listeners"]["total"]
        self.now_playing_playlist = radio_info["now_playing"]["playlist"]
        self.now_playing_song_title = radio_info["now_playing"]["song"]["title"]
        self.now_playing_song_artist = radio_info["now_playing"]["song"]["artist"]
        self.now_playing_song_album = radio_info["now_playing"]["song"]["album"]
        ###
        # What if radio["playing_next"] is None ??
        ###
        self.next_playing_playlist = radio_info["playing_next"]["playlist"]
        self.next_playing_song_title = radio_info["playing_next"]["song"]["title"]
        self.next_playing_song_artist = radio_info["playing_next"]["song"]["artist"]
        self.next_playing_song_album = radio_info["playing_next"]["song"]["album"]
```

Having the above, trying to figure out how to refactor this, so that I can check if some of the nodes are `None` and handle this accordingly.
Additionally starting out with unit testing, and besides error handling was thinking about best practices of unit testing this object.
Should I create a method for each property and unit test with `pytest.mark.parametrize` for example, or is this considered redundant and not necessary ?

Comment: I would suggest to use a library that offers JSON parsing according to a schema, e.g. `pydantic` and friends.

Comment: Thank you very much ! However would like to know the general approach to unit testing a class like this. Do you have each attribute set by a method or do you test it by changing `radio_info` and check the outcome?